# Migrating Windows form unit tests to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, unit-testing

I have a project in Winforms where I use MBUnit for Unit testing.Now we are planning to migrate this project(in Winforms) to WPF. 
Should we have to write the unit testing from scratch for WPF or can we reuse the existing Windows forms unit test?

As we all know WPF is declarative but internally it converts to c# code. So I feel it could reused. If any body have worked in this kind of a scenario please help.

What I know is all "buts" and "ifs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends how much separation you have between your UI code and your business logic. In an ideal scenario you have clear separation which means your business logic will be agnostic of the UI technology and port easily. However, if your UI code and business logic is tangled and makes assumptions about the UI technology it will be harder.

On a separate note:
WPF is a very testable and encourages the unit test friendly coding pattern Model View View Model (MVVM). I strongly encourage you to research MVVM and unit testing if you're starting a new WPF project.

Comment: seems you were reading my thoughts while I was typing, and you're a faster typist. :)

Comment: I used MVP pattern for my existing application. I think the logic is clearly separated. Thanks for the help TGH

Answer (score 3):

Wow ... seems like it has heaps of hype ... but it's from 4 years ago at best (7 at most ...)

Having said that, the answer would be: maybe.

If your unit tests test only logic and methods to ensure valid behavior, you should be good.

If your unit tests are entangled into the winforms and depend on them for results, you won't be that good.

Good unit tests should not care about the view, and should test the logic/model of your application. MVVM is very friendly to this approach.

Without code or examples, it's really hard to answer your question.

Comment: Yes. I totally I agree with this statement "Good unit tests should not care about the view". To achieve that we need to strict separation of business logic code. Couldn't add the code as it was proprietary. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern in the WinForms application as I wanted to unit test presentation logic. MVP pattern provides a layer of abstraction between your controls and presentation logic. If your WinForms application written using this pattern, or a variation of this pattern, then you should be able to re-use some of the unit tests.

When unit testing WPF application, you should probably be using MVVM pattern. In MVVM pattern the majority of presentation logic lives in your view models. View models are not coupled to UI elements, therefore they should be unit testable.

My gut feeling is that it's a bad idea and if this was me, then I would write unit tests from scratch for my WPF appplication.

Comment: Bang on. I've used MVP pattern for my existing application. I think the logic is clearly separated.